# Emoji support on Ckeditor react js

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, emoji

I'm using Ckeditor 4 in my react js application and i figured out that if I copy an emoji from Telegram for example, the emoji doesn't work as expected.

I'm using the plugin:

> react-ckeditor-component

Any suggestion?

Comment: For emoji handling https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/emoji

Comment: Which version of React are you using? This library seems to be pretty limiting.

Comment: "react": "^17.0.2"